# Change image size on click of button in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on image upload and I need to add functionality for image shapes.

There are buttons for landscape, portrait, square and panoramic. When the user clicks any of these, the div shape will change accordingly.

This is the code for the square shape but when I click on the square shape, it stretches the image. I want to change the shape of the div without stretching the image.

```
$('#Square').on('click', function(){
    var images = $("#uploadedImage");
    for(i=0; i<images.length; i++)
        images[i].onload = centerImage(images[i]);

    function centerImage(img) {
        if (img.width > img.height ) {
            var y = 160;
            var x = img.width/img.height*y;
            var marx = (x-y)/2;
            img.style.height = y+"px";
            img.style.marginLeft = -(marx) + "px";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to recreate running example without more generalized code, but your function clearly changes the dimensions of variable img, the image passed in to the function, and not any div or other element besides the image that was clicked. If you want to change a div based on the same HxW test of the image, change the img.* parts of your function to $('#DivYouWant').* and you should get on the right track. Something along the lines of:

```
 function centerImage(img) {
        if (img.width > img.height ) {
            var y = 160;
            var x = img.width/img.height*y;
            var marx = (x-y)/2;
            $('#DivYouWannaMod').height = y+"px";
            $('#DivYouWannaMod').marginLeft = -(marx) + "px";
        }
    }
```